# Integrate, how to prove

Tags: integration

$p$, $q$ are positive natural numbers. How to prove this:

$$\int_{0}^1(1-x^p)^{1/q}\,dx=\int_{0}^1(1-x^q)^{1/p}\,dx$$

Comment: This is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: To understand the symmetry, imagine that you are dealing with a [superelliptic shape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) of equation $x^p+y^q=1$. Then we have $y=\sqrt[q]{1-x^p}$ and $x=\sqrt[p]{1-y^q}$, from where it follows that its area can be expressed as either $\int_{0}^1(1-x^p)^{1/q}\,dx$, or as $\int_{0}^1(1-x^q)^{1/p}\,dx$, both expressions being therefore equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^p)^{1/q}\,dx = \frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^{1}z^{\frac{1}{p}-1}(1-z)^{\frac{1}{q}}\,dz = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{q}+1\right)}{p\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+1\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{q}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+1\right)}$$
that is clearly a symmetric expression in $p$ and $q$.